# MathJax download cannot load in a local web page

Tags: mathjax

I downloaded the latest copy of MathJax through Git, installed it somewhere, and wrote the following document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Notes - Wenke's Patterns in Prehistory</title>
    <script id="MathJax-script" async src="../../../../MathJax/e5/tex-chtml.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    $ e^i $
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try to run it in a browser the console prints the message `Loading failed for the <script> with source “file:///home/username/underconstruction/MathJax/e5/tex-chtml.js”.`.

I believe the `README.md` file that comes with the download indicated that `tex-chtml.js` was supposed to be the file to link in the HTML document.  I've seen elsewhere reference to a `MathJax.js` file but that was not included in my download.

Comment: The error indicates that the file is in the wrong location. That's not really a MathJax issue.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger does that error only come up when the file is not found?  I searched the error and there seemed to be other ways the error would arise.  If that is the case, why wouldn't they call it "file not found" like in every other language?

Comment: yes "Loading failed for the <script> with source ..." is a standard Firefox error message.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger Yeah but that wasn't my questio... never mind, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify the location ("../..") of the file "tex-chtml.js" relative to the location of the HTML-page containing $e^i$. The file is likely not there as the warning message indicates. If you specify a path relative to the current HTML-page be also sure that the relative path is the same on your localhost and on the server.

A simple method for using MathJax is given on https://www.mathjax.org.
You do not need to download MathJax from anywhere. Just include the following lines in your HTML-file:

```
<head>    
  <script>
    MathJax = {tex: {inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]}};
  </script> 
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
  <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: I avoided the linked source because, I suspect, that causes bandwidth problems on the host's end if everyone is repeatedly fetching something from them.  So I figured it would be better practice if I installed the source.  But you're right, the issue was a typo in the file path, namely it should have been `es5` rather than `e5`.